# using select options to get value in asp.net razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I want to create a select option to input one of a few fixed values and have it return a matching value to a variable similar to how the input text fields, how would I do this? This was my attempt, the `<input type="text">` works fine but the select types return null.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Add new patient</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" asp-for="patientModel.PatientID" placeholder="Patient ID" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="patientModel.FirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="patientModel.SecondName" placeholder="Second Name" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="patientModel.Location" placeholder="Location" />
        <select id="active" name="active" asp-for="patientModel.Sex">
            <option value="ACTIVE">MALE</option>
            <option value="INACTIVE">FEMALE</option>
            <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
        </select>
        <select id="active" name="active" asp-for="patientModel.Active">
            <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
            <option value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

```
    public class addnewpatientModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public PatientModel patientModel { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/index");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link. I think you'll find an answer [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists)

The select element has a name attribute. This is used as the key for any selected value(s) when a form is submitted. You can access the value by passing the key as an indexer to the Request.

```
var value = Request.Form["active"];
```

The recommended approach, however is to add a suitable property to the PageModel and to allow model binding to apply the posted value to the property:

```
public class addnewpatientModel : PageModel
 {
    [BindProperty]
    public int active { get; set; }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        // posted value is assigned to the Number property automatically
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the name attribute for the select tag or just remove it:

```
<select id="sex" name="patientModel.Sex" asp-for="patientModel.Sex">

<select id="active" name="patientModel.Active" asp-for="patientModel.Active">
```